# Streaming sequence of image with Live555

Tags: c++, visual-studio, live555

Instead of using:

```
videoSink->startPlaying(*videoSource, afterPlaying, videoSink);
```

I'm looking for a way to feed videoSink image by image, one after another. 
This way I can get my webcam images and feed them to the Live555 for streaming.

Is that possbile?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can accomplish that using the [live555 event trigger of the DeviceSource](http://www.live555.com/liveMedia/doxygen/html/DeviceSource_8hh.html) mechanism. Searching the live555 mailing list for EventTrigger, DeviceSource should provide you with a way to get started. AFAIR there was a section on live sources in the FAQ.

I would advise you to encode the data before hand. You can use FFMPEG to encode the JPG's into a frame and send it off to Live555 to be streamed as done [similarly to this example project](https://www.imc-store.com.au/Articles.asp?ID=278). Live555 has sinks for many video codecs so you'll have to use the appropriate sink.